# Queue between Python processes without using the multiprocessing module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to start a child process that doesn't share its parent process's Python interpreter (Jython and CPython). I would like to use a convenient IPC tool like `Queue.Queue` or `multiprocessing.Connection`.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: I don't think multiprocessing.Connection requires the processes being childs of the same Python process.

Comment: It seems you're right. Unfortunately the `multiprocessing` module is not available in Jython.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a message queue library like [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/). It has language bindings for Python and Java, your Jython scripts would need to use the Java classes of these bindings.
Alternatively, there's a pure Python message queue [snakeMQ](http://www.snakemq.net/). This should run in both C-Python and Jython as it does not require native libraries.
You could encode your messages if it is more than strings and numbers, using JSON, or pickle (I'm not sure if pickle output is compatible between C-Python and Jython, though).